# email signature using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I’m new to React and Javascript and I am having a challenge.

It looks like this:

**email signature generator**

It’s important to have consisten email signatures in a given company.

The application should be written as a client-side one that generates signatures for employees.

It’s supposed to look like this:

Jane Doe // (name)

Frontend-Developer // (job title)

jdoe@company.com // (email address)

Company Inc. // (company info)

12345 City

Every employee has a different name, email, job title of course.

The email address always starts with the first letter of the first name and is then followed by the last name and @company.com

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide us a work in progress solution. We cannot implement the whole thing for you.

Comment: It’s coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need some data.

I would have an object containing the company information, and an array of employee data:

```
const company = {
  companyName: 'Bozos Inc',
  zipCode: 90210,
  address: '1234 Turkey Road.'
}

const employees = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', jobTitle: 'Engineer' },
  { firstName: 'Karen', lastName: 'Jones', jobTitle: 'Manager' }
];
```

Then you need a component that creates a signature card for each employee given a set of employee data, and some company information.

```
function Signature({ employee, company }) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="employee">
        <div className="name">{employee.firstName} {employee.lastName}</div>
        <div>{employee.jobTitle}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="company">
        <div>{company.name}</div>
        <div>{company.address}</div>
        <div>{company.zipCode}</div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  )
}
```

And maybe a way to iterate over that employee information returning each signature card:

```
function Signatures({ employees, company }) {
  return employees.map((employee, key) => {
    return <Signature key={key} employee={employee} company={company} />
  });
}
```

Putting it all togther might give you something like this:

```js
function Signature({ employee, company }) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="employee">
        <div className="name">{employee.firstName} {employee.lastName}</div>
        <div>{employee.jobTitle}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="company">
        <div>{company.name}</div>
        <div>{company.address}</div>
        <div>{company.zipCode}</div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  )
}

function Signatures({ employees, company }) {
  return employees.map((employee, key) => {
    return <Signature key={key} employee={employee} company={company} />
  });
}

const company = {
  companyName: 'Bozos Inc',
  zipCode: 90210,
  address: '1234 Turkey Road.'
}

const employees = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', jobTitle: 'Engineer' },
  { firstName: 'Karen', lastName: 'Jones', jobTitle: 'Manager' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Signatures company={company} employees={employees} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.company {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  color: #000088;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using an email signature that is applied on the server-side as part of the transport?
I use this for myself and my clients:
[Exclaimer Cloud for Office 365](https://www.exclaimer.com/exclaimer-cloud/signatures-for-office-365/?utm_source=SocialEngagement&utm_medium=Stackoverflow)

and [Exclaimer for Exchange Server](https://www.exclaimer.com/signature-manager-exchange-edition/?utm_source=SocialEngagement&utm_medium=Stackoverflow)